# why do I get warning on scipy sparse column slicing?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Scipy sparse documentation of csr_matrix says that this kind of matrix is efficient for row slicing. Using this code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

dok = sparse.dok_matrix((5,1))
dok[1,0] = 1

data = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
row = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
col = np.array([0,1,2,3,4])
csr = sparse.csr_matrix((data, (row, col)))
csr[:, 0] += dok
```

I get this warning:

```
SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
```

Why am I getting this warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unrelated to row vs. column. Essentially, you are forcing scipy to insert elements in the middle of two arrays, which as the warning says is expensive.

Let's look at the internal representation of csr before and after the in-place modification to confirm this:

```
>>> csr.data
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64)
>>> csr.indices
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32)
>>> 
>>> csr[:, 0] += dok
/home/paul/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:742: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  SparseEfficiencyWarning)
>>> csr.data
array([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64)
>>> csr.indices
array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int32)
```

A bit of background: The compressed sparse row and column formats essentially only store nonzeros. They do this in a packed way using vectors to store the nonzero values and their coordinates in a specific order. If an operation adds new nonzeros they typically can't be appended but must be inserted, which is what we see in the example and what makes it expensive.

Comment: I don't understand how I'm trying to *insert in the middle of two arrays*. Wich are the two arrays?

Comment: Thanks for taking your time your ans is very useful!

Comment: So which should be the efficient way to perform the task? Converting the matrix into lil format and then back again into csr format is too expensive (I am repeating this in a loop).

Comment: Pretty much depends on what you are doing before and afterwards. If it's just the one modification and everything else is well handled by csr format I'd ignore the warning. In general you'd have to arrange your algorithm in way that minimizes the amount of conversions required, so for example you would try and group operations that change the sparsity structure etc.

Comment: ok, yes, I tried to minimize these modifications on the matrix and they are grouped in the unique step that changes column values. After that I compute multpilications and other math operations. Eventually the computation ends and the loop goes through this modification step again. I think I'm just going to ignore it.